# R.Mapcalc giving only blank maps as result

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator

No matter what function I put in the r.mapcalc in the GRASS GUI I get a blank map full of null values. I even tried DEM+0 (I can see my DEM) and this also yielded a blank map.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you haven't set computational region correctly? Try running g.region before r.mapcalc:

```
g.region rast=DEM
```

This makes the computational region match the extent of your map DEM.

See also: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region